# Reorder bars in geom_bar ggplot2 by value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a bar-plot where the plot is ordered from the `miRNA` with the highest `value` to the `miRNA` with the lowest. Why does my code not work?

```
> head(corr.m)

        miRNA         variable value
1    mmu-miR-532-3p      pos     7
2    mmu-miR-1983        pos    75
3    mmu-miR-301a-3p     pos    70
4    mmu-miR-96-5p       pos     5
5    mmu-miR-139-5p      pos    10
6    mmu-miR-5097        pos    47

ggplot(corr.m, aes(x=reorder(miRNA, value), y=value, fill=variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Answer (score 319, accepted):

Your code works fine, except that the barplot is ordered from low to high. When you want to order the bars from high to low, you will have to add a `-`sign before `value`:

```
ggplot(corr.m, aes(x = reorder(miRNA, -value), y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

which gives:

[image]

---

**Used data:**

```
corr.m <- structure(list(miRNA = structure(c(5L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("mmu-miR-139-5p", "mmu-miR-1983", "mmu-miR-301a-3p", "mmu-miR-5097", "mmu-miR-532-3p", "mmu-miR-96-5p"), class = "factor"),
                         variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "pos", class = "factor"),
                         value = c(7L, 75L, 70L, 5L, 10L, 47L)),
                    class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: it does not get ordered in my plot for some reason

Comment: @user3741035 Strange. Did you use it on the sample dataset you provided above or on the whole dataset?

Comment: Which version of R & ggplot are you using? Can you also privede a larger sample dataset (preferrably with more than one value for `variable`)?

Comment: found the solution: I had loaded library(gplots) which messed up things

Comment: nice tip! how does it work BTW? I don't get why adding - should invert the order.

Comment: @Bakaburg It tells R to use decreasing order instead of increasing.

Comment: I meant practically how is it implemented; Guess I should read the code inside.

Comment: the reordering doesn't work for me neither.... And i don't use library(gplots).. I have ggplot2_2.1.0 R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks). do you have anothersuggestions, where I am wrong?

Comment: @maycca It is giving me the correct result (on both OSX 10.10.4 / Windows 7, R 3.2.3 & ggplot2 2.1.0). Maybe you should start with a fresh session?

Comment: Thank, I was doing that on my data and it didn't work... but I've fixed the problem - I firstly needed to convert my factors from numeric to character. and then to factors ! and no directly the numeric to factors. It workd great now ! ;)

Comment: "object 'value' not found" This answer seems to be invalid.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa The answer is still valid (just checked). The error indicates that the column `value` isn't in your data. You might want to use another column for reordering?

Comment: @LuísdeSousa Did you downvote? Anyway, as I said: the answer I posted above still gives the same output with the latest versions of R & ggplot2

Comment: @Jaap I can not find what could be wrong on my side. Copy paste from your answer results in the error above.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa Is there a `value`-column in your data?

Comment: @Jaap the column has a different name, but naturally I am changing the `y` and `x` arguments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189928/discussion-between-jaap-and-luis-de-sousa).

Answer (score 6):

Aside from what @Jaap answered, there are two other ways to order the plot:

1: By using `desc` argument for value:

```
ggplot(corr.m, aes(x = reorder(miRNA, desc(value)), y = value, fill = variable)) + 
   geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

2: By releveling the miRNA factor and omitting `reorder` argument:

```
corr.m %>%
   arrange(desc(value)) %>%
   mutate(miRNA = factor(miRNA, levels = unique(miRNA))) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = miRNA, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
   geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is creating the variable as a `factor` where the factor `levels` are in decreasing order based on your value variable.

**decreasing = TRUE**

```r
library(ggplot2)
# Create factor column with decreasing order TRUE
corr.m$miRNA <- factor(corr.m$miRNA, levels = corr.m$miRNA[order(corr.m$value, decreasing = TRUE)])

ggplot(corr.m, aes(x=miRNA, y=value, fill=variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

**decreasing = FALSE**

```r
library(ggplot2)
# Create factor column with decreasing order FALSE
corr.m$miRNA <- factor(corr.m$miRNA, levels = corr.m$miRNA[order(corr.m$value, decreasing = FALSE)])

ggplot(corr.m, aes(x=miRNA, y=value, fill=variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>