# Ranking Y-Axis Based on Variable in ggplot2 (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, reshape2

I have a data set I am building stacked bar graphs in ggplot2. Each observation (Life) is located on the y axis with the bar graph extending parallel with the x-axis values. However, I would like to rank these variables based a ranking that is unrelated to the x-axis values (Earth, Wind, Fire and Water), but is  being merged from another data set. 
Main Data:

```
Life    Earth   Wind    Fire       Water    
A      2.72    1.22    0.860220476  2.86    
B      2.11    1       0.660225123  2.26    
C      0.67    0.31    0.1900664    0.69
```

Rank Data:

```
Life Rank
A     3
B     1
C     2
```

I am looking for Life B "Bar" to be at the top of the y-axis and Life A "Bar" to be at the bottom. The default just puts them in alphabetical order. How can I order these so the Rank 1 bar  is at the top and Rank 3 is at the bottom?

Here is my code:

```
require(reshape2)
require(ggplot2)
bars1 <- read.csv("Renown.csv",header=T,skip = 0,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
Rank <- read.csv("Rank.csv",header=T,skip = 0,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
bars1 <- aggregate(.~Lifestyle, data=bars1, FUN=mean)
bars1 <- melt(bars1, id.vars = "Life")
bars1 <- merge(bars1, Rank, by="Life")
bars1 <- ggplot(bars1, aes(x = Life, y = value , fill=variable)) + geom_bar(stat='identity')  + coord_flip()
```

Thanks!

Comment: try `bars1$Life <- factor(bars1$Life,c("B","C","A"))`

Comment: likely a duplicate, possibly of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664007/reorder-bars-in-geom-bar-ggplot2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn `Life` into a factor with the ordering based on `Rank`

```
bars1$Life = factor(bars1$Life, levels = Rank[order(-Rank$Rank),]$Life)
```

[image]