# Sorting DataFrame for ggplot barplot

Tags: r

I have a data frame `df1` and want to draw a barplot of `AccountExecutive` and their corresponding `ClearRate` where the bars are arranged so that it is decreasing from left to right.

I tried this code but the resulting graph still reflects `AccountExecutive` order as it appears in `df1`

```
ggplot(arrange(df1, -ClearRate), aes(x = AccountExecutive, y = ClearRate)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Can anyone help me correcting this code?

NOTE: Not a duplicate of the previous question because that one asks for an arbitrary positioning of the x axis labels. This question asks how to sort x-axis labels considering their y-axis values.

Comment: So I used this code 'ggplot(df1, aes(x = fct_infreq(AccountExecutive), 
  y = ClearRate)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(fill=Area)) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0.5))' but it still doesn't work.

Comment: As we can't see what's on your screen: What do you mean "it still doesn't work". Please, provide a [mcve]. Thank you.

Comment: If you are using `geom_bar(stat="identity")` you probably do have a frequency table already. Then you probably need to use `forcats::fct_reorder(AccountExecutive, ClearRate)`. However, this is only a shot in the dark as you haven't provided a [mcve].

Comment: I think you got it correctly. It is now working. Thanks Nonetheless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one  the code below should reorder AE according to clearance rate

```
ggplot(df1,aes(x=reorder(AccountExecutive,-ClearRate),y=ClearRate))+geom_bar(stat"identity")
```

here is the more about reorder function
[Reorder bars in geom_bar ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664007/reorder-bars-in-geom-bar-ggplot2)