# Order of boxplot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

here is my code:

```
> hdata$Mono<- factor(hdata$Mon)

> ggplot(hdata, aes(y= Test1, x= Mono))+ geom_boxplot()
```

And this is what it is giving:

[image]

I want to format the x axis in a way so that it will start from 12 and go like this 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ,7, 8

Comment: look at the answer here  just change the variable and sign in reorder:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42184869/sorting-dataframe-for-ggplot-barplot/42186399#42186399

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do

```
hdata$Mono<- factor(hdata$Mon, levels = c(12, 1:8))
```

factor by default orders the levels in ascending order. You can order them yourself by using the `levels` argument.