# Sorting higher to lower in a bar plot on ggplot2 with a loop

Tags: r, loops, sorting, plot, ggplot2

I want to introduce some element into my loop that sort all bars of the bar plots higher to lower, the loop I wrote is the following (it plots bar plots of all the variables of my dataframe and saves them in a list):

`bar_list <- list()
for(i in names(X4)) {
  bar_list[[i]] = ggplot(X4, aes(x=Country, y=X4[,i])) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + labs(y=names(X4[,i])) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, size = 6))}
bar_list$NI1_3gcoverage`

Someone can help me to introduce an element into the loop that reorder bars of the plots higher to lower to each plot?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Did you try `reorder`?  Lots of example around, including [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664007/reorder-bars-in-geom-bar-ggplot2).

Comment: I might add that I have found commands and help for sort a single bar plot, but not for doing it within a loop.

Comment: Thanks for help aosmith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short reproducible example would be nice.

I usually do it using `reorder` on the x value in `aes` like that:

`aes(x = reorder(Country, X4[, i]), y = X4[,i])`