# make geom_bar show values in the ascending order

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

Although my query shows me values in descending order, ggplot then displays them alphabetically instead of ascending order.

[image]

Known solutions to this problem haven't seem to work. They suggest using Reorder or factor for values, which didn't work in this case

This is my code:

```
boxoffice %>%
  group_by(studio) %>%
  summarise(movies_made = n()) %>%
  arrange(desc(movies_made)) %>%
  top_n(10) %>%
  arrange(desc(movies_made)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = studio, y = movies_made, fill = studio, label = as.character(movies_made))) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  geom_label(label.size = 1, size = 5, color = "white") +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  ylab("Movies Made") +
  xlab("Studio")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reorder bars in geom\_bar ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664007/reorder-bars-in-geom-bar-ggplot2)

Comment: @markus that solution didn't work

Comment: Have you tried with `reorder()` ?

Comment: @markus, yes. With various syntax. I get:
"Error in tapply(X = X, INDEX = x, FUN = FUN, ...)

Comment: Then please make your problem reproducible. Add output of `dput(head(boxoffice, 20))` at the end of your question.

Comment: `x = reorder(studio, -movies_made)` works for me…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to convert `boxoffice$studio` to an ordered factor. **ggplot** will then respect the order of rows in the data set, rather than alphabetizing. Your dplyr chain will look like this:

```
boxoffice %>%
  group_by(studio) %>%
  summarise(movies_made = n()) %>%
  arrange(desc(movies_made)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% # ungroup
  mutate(studio = factor(studio, studio, ordered = T)) %>% # convert variable
  top_n(10) %>%
  arrange(desc(movies_made)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = studio, y... (rest of plotting code)
```

Comment: You basically nailed it. I'm getting what I want. Right now it's in descending order, but if I wanted to make it ascending, how would I go about it? I got rid of desc(), and it changed the order of data frame, but the plot stayed the same

Comment: Your code has `desc` twice, actually: right before the new `ungroup` line and then again right after `top_n`. Try removing both.

Comment: You're a wizard!

Answer (score 1):

for those wanting a more complete example, here's where I got:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# get some dummy data
boxoffice = boxoffice::boxoffice(dates=as.Date("2017-1-1"))

df <- (
  boxoffice %>%
  group_by(distributor) %>%
  summarise(movies_made = n()) %>%
  mutate(studio=reorder(distributor, -movies_made)) %>%
  top_n(10))

ggplot(df, aes(x=distributor, y=movies_made)) + geom_col()
```