# reorder bars of ggplot with increasing y value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have to reorder the bars of the plot with increasing value of y(nbi).
Thanks in advance!

```
#NBI*Sig_lip
p4 <-ggplot(DF, aes(x=sig_lip, y=nbi, fill=sig_lip)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="bar",show.legend = TRUE) +  
  stat_summary(func="sd", geom="errorbar") + 
  theme_minimal()
p4+ coord_flip()
p4 + ggtitle(label = "nbi associated to signaling lipids")
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reorder bars in geom\_bar ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664007/reorder-bars-in-geom-bar-ggplot2)

Comment: Actually, my bad I'm not sure the solution proposed in this post will work for your example. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here your issue to reorder bargraph is that you are calculating the mean and the standard deviation in `ggplot2`. So, if you pass the "classic" `reorder(x, -y)`, it will set the order based on the individual values of y not the mean.

So, you need to calculate Mean and SD before passing nbi as an argument in `ggplot2`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

DF %>% group_by(sig_lip) %>%
  summarise(Mean = mean(nbi, na.rm = TRUE),
            SD = sd(nbi, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(sig_lip,-Mean), y = Mean, fill = sig_lip))+
  geom_col()+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Mean-SD, ymax = Mean+SD))
```

Does it answer your question ?

If not, please provide a reproducible example of your dataset by follwoign this guide: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks! I just had to add:                                                                                     coord_flip(xlim = NULL, ylim = NULL, expand = TRUE, clip = "on"                                                    to flip the coordinates correctly!