# Ordering geom_bar() without a y defined variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

Is there a way to order the bars in `geom_bar()` when `y` is just the count of `x`?

Example:

```
ggplot(dat) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = feature_1))
```

I tried using `reorder()` but it requires a defined `y` variable within `aes()`.

Comment: Not 100% sure whether there is a way to achieve this with geom_bar ... instead I would go for the easy solution and pre-compute the counts.

Comment: Kind of similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664007/reorder-bars-in-geom-bar-ggplot2 My answer below based on this link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made up data:

```
dfexmpl <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
         group = c("a","a","a","a","a","a",
                   "a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b",
                   "b","b","b","b","b","b"))
```

plot code - reorder is doing the work of arranging by count:

```
dfexmpl %>%
group_by(group) %>%
mutate(count = n()) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = reorder(group, -count), y = count)) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

results in:
[image]